# How to recursively create a directory if it does NOT yet exist?

Tags: shell-script, bash-scripting

This seems like a general utility and am wondering if anything already exists.  I'm trying to place a timestamped logfile in a directory after a script runs, but need to make sure the subdirectory (and any directories along the chain) exist first.

For example, if the full relative path is `./2014/Backups/Logfiles`, I'd like to check if `2014` does not exist, create it, if `Backups` does not exist, create it, if `Logfiles` does not exist, create it....

So far I've got something like this that (but it's only one step):
LOGFILE_DIRECTORY="./2014/Backups/Logfiles"

```
if [ ! -d "$LOGFILE_DIRECTORY" ]; then
  mkdir "$LOGFILE_DIRECTORY" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
fi
```

Comment: I know I'm necro-ing this question, but if you'll edit your "solution" edit out and add it as an answer, I'll upvote both question and answer.

Comment: Added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
mkdir -p <path-to-desired-directory>
```

From the man page:

```
   -p, --parents
      no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```